# Gnome Terminal tab completion placing text in odd areas

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, gnome-terminal

Using tab completion in gnome-terminal appears to be placing text in odd areas, such as to the left (on top of my prompt) or above, sometimes. Here is an example of what happens when it places it over my prompt.

[image]

Is this a fixable thing?

Comment: Are you using the default bash & terminal? Anything unusual with your .bashrc or other config? Looks a little different. Try using a default config & see if it still happens?

Comment: Different font and prompt, but otherwise default.

Comment: Show us your `$PS1`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to enclose the non-printable characters of your prompt between `\[` and `\]`. This is required for bash to be able to keep track of the column where its cursor is.